# В чем разница при удалении элементов списка в цикле со срезом и без

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список

Я знаю, что такое срезы и пользуюсь ими, но не понимаю принципиальную разницу в этих двух примерах, почему со срезом удается удалить список полностью? Окей. У нас меняется индекс во время одновременной итерации и удаления, из-за этого такие последствия. НО как срез решает эту проблему?

```
>>> somelist = range(10)
>>> for x in somelist:
...     somelist.remove(x)
>>> somelist
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

>>> somelist = list(range(10))
>>> for x in somelist[:]:
...     somelist.remove(x)
>>> somelist
[]
```

Comment: somelist[:] -  это копия

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нельзя изменять (уменьшать / увеличивать) число элементов списка во время итерирования по нему. Это приведет к неожиданным и неприятным эффектам.

Пример:

```
In [71]: items = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

In [72]: for x in items:
    ...:     items.remove(x)
    ...:     print(x, items)
    ...:
0 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
2 [1, 3, 4, 5]
4 [1, 3, 5]
```

в итоге из списка не удалились элементы с четным индексом.

Чтобы понять как это произошло можно попробовать сэмулировать данное поведение:

```
In [82]: items = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

In [83]: items_iter = iter(items)  # эмуляция цикла `for x in items:`

In [84]: next(items_iter)
Out[84]: 0

In [85]: items.remove(0)

In [86]: print(items)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [87]: next(items_iter)
Out[87]: 2

In [88]: items.remove(2)

In [89]: print(items)
[1, 3, 4, 5]

In [90]: next(items_iter)
Out[90]: 4

In [91]: items.remove(4)

In [92]: print(items)
[1, 3, 5]
```

---

когда вы используете `for x in somelist[:]:` - вы итерируетесь по **копии** и соответственно удаление элементов из оригинального списка `somelist` не влияет на итерирование по **копии**.

Можно убедиться что `somelist` и `somelist[:]` - это разные и независимые  объекты:

```
In [93]: id(somelist)
Out[93]: 2487734832008

In [94]: id(somelist[:])
Out[94]: 2487700013128

In [95]: somelist is somelist[:]
Out[95]: False
```

**Совет:** никогда не изменяйте число элементов списка во время итерирования по нему дабы избежать подобных эффектов